# Starting new process

Tags: c#, .net

Under my solution I have 2 projects Project A console application , Project B Winforms Window.

How I can From Project B to start new process with console application from Project A ?

I tried to making it via

```
    Process note = new Process();

    note.StartInfo.FileName   = "note.exe";
    note.StartInfo.Arguments = "123";

    note.Start();
```

But in that way i cant debug both processes from one vs instance . Any idea ?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the only reason that you want to start the two projects is that you want to be able to debug both of them you can also configure your solution to have multiple startup projects:

> *Solution -> Properties -> Set Startup Projects...*

If you are going to start the other project as a separate project anyway, you could use

> *Debug -> Attach to Process*

to attach to the newly started process. Then you will also be able to debug both processes in Visual Studio. Attaching the debugger can also be achieved programmatically. In project A you can add the following code to the `Main` method:

```
#if DEBUG
    System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Launch();
#endif
```

In the dialog that will then pop up you can select the already running instance of Visual Studio.

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to start the Startup Project via F5 (or Debug > Start Debugging) and the second one by right-clicking the project and going Debug > Start New Instance.

Answer (score 0):

You can start debugger in the application launched by the following statement

System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Break()

then you can choose the visual studio instance and start debugging.